# a3m-like module for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, codeigniter, codeigniter-a3m

I have short and simple one: is there any RoR plugin/gem similar to [a3m](https://code.google.com/p/a3m/) module for CodeIgniter? I'm not looking for a Swiss-army-knife solution, and I've found a lot gems that cover only specific aspect of `a3m`'s functionality. So it's OK if you point me to several gems for authentication/authorisation and OpenID/OAuth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For authentication:

- [authlogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic)
- [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)
- [clearance](https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance)
- [sorcery](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery)
- [omniauth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth)

For authorization:

- [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan)
- [cantango](https://github.com/kristianmandrup/cantango)